# How to make seperate comment section for each item

Tags: python, django

I am making django app I have a problem I dont have idea how to make seperate comment section to each Item. I do not want to have same comments for every Item on a page.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(default='')
```

views.py

```
class ShopDetailView(DetailView):
model = Item 
template_name = 'shop/detail.html'
context_object_name = 'item'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
    return context
```

Comment: This is a `ListView`, `DetailView`?

Comment: It is a DetailView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `DetailView`, you can obtain the related comments with:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(item=self.object)
    return context
```

It makes however not much sense to work with a `OneToOneField` here, since that means that each item can only have *at most one* comment. You probably want a many-to-one relation, and thus work with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(default='')
```